# Massless Tachyon in 2D

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, tachyon

Referring to a large number of works on 2D bosonic string theory with particular attention on the worldsheet description of 2D black hole solution (cigar CFT) I don't understand why the tachyonic field is massless in 2-dimensional bosonic string theory?

Comment: To receive useful concise answers, consider adding relevant references.

Answer (score 2):

The ground state in bosonic string theory is defined such that,

$$\hat p^\mu |0;p\rangle = p^\mu|0;p\rangle, \quad \alpha^i_n |0;p\rangle = \tilde \alpha^i_n |0;p\rangle = 0, \quad n >0.$$

We can then add $\alpha$ or $\tilde \alpha$ operators to build further states. The mass formula for these states turns out to be (after using zeta function regularisation or another trick),

$$M^2 = \frac{4}{\alpha'} \left( N - \frac{D-2}{24}\right)=\frac{4}{\alpha'} \left(\tilde N - \frac{D-2}{24}\right).$$

For $N=0$, we have the mass of the tachyon, which clearly vanishes for $D=2$ dimensions, though not to be confused with the dimension of the worldsheet.

Of course, to preserve $SO(1,D-1)$ Lorentz symmetry, one must have $D=26$ to ensure the first excited states are massless (cf. Wigner's classification of representations of the Poincaré group).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I actually have another confusion.  The tachyon excitation can be described, in spacetime point of view, by a tachyonic field, a scalar T(X), governed by a target-space action, still in two dimensions (spacetime). This action is usually written as follows

$$
S\sim \int d^2X\sqrt{G}e^{\phi}(R+(\nabla\phi)^2+(\nabla T)^2-2T^2-8)
$$

Isn't the term quadratic in T a mass term ?